# Can you access a static variable in another static variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, static, nameerror

I was using a variable that i had initialized in the line before it and the console gave me the following error:

> NameError: name 'Purchase' is not defined

This is my code that throws this exception

```
class Purchase:
   list_of_items = ["Cake", "Soap", "Jam", "Cereal", "Hand Sanitizer", "Biscuits", "Bread"]
   list_of_count_of_each_item_sold = [0] * Purchase.list_of_items
```

I don't understand why this happens, because when i use static variable in class method no such error ever occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the line `list_of_count_of_each_item_sold = [0] * Purchase.list_of_items` is evaluated the scope is already inside the class, so there is no need to use `Purchase.list_of_items`. You can directly access `list_of_items`:

```py
class Purchase:
    list_of_items = ["Cake", "Soap", "Jam", "Cereal", "Hand Sanitizer", "Biscuits", "Bread"]
    list_of_count_of_each_item_sold = [0] * list_of_items
```

Additonally to initialize `list_of_count_of_each_item_sold` correctly with a `0` for each item in `list_of_items` you have to multiply `[0]` with the length of `list_of_items` by using `len()`.

```py
class Purchase:
    list_of_items = ["Cake", "Soap", "Jam", "Cereal", "Hand Sanitizer", "Biscuits", "Bread"]
    list_of_count_of_each_item_sold = [0] * len(list_of_items)
```